# "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Model::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in TechnicienController.php

Tags: laravel

From my form I want to fill in both tables technician and user knowing that I have a one-to-one connection I put the form to you. Someone would have an idea on how to fill in the tables at once from my form.

[image: form]

**Model1**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function technicien()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\technicien');

}

use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password','nom','prenom','tel','mobil','role',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

**Model2**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class technicien extends Model
{

    public function zoneintervention()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\zoneintervention','technicien_zone','technicien_id','zoneintervention_id');

}
    public function metier()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\metier','technicien_metier','technicien_id','metier_id');

}
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function tarificationtache()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tarificationtache::class);
}

}
```

**create .blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <ul>
    @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
     <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action=" {{url ('technicien')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Nom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{ old('nom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('nom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nom') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Prenom</label>
                <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="prenom" value="{{ old('prenom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('prenom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('prenom') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Telephone</label>
                <input id="tel" type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" value="{{ old('tel') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('tel'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('tel') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Mobile</label>
                <input id="mobil" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobil" value="{{ old('mobil') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('mobile'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('mobil') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Role</label>
                <input id="role" type="text" class="form-control" name="role" value="{{ old('role') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('role'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('role') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="">E-Mail Address</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="password">Password</label>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="password_confirmation" type="password_" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" value="{{ old('password_confirmation') }}" required s>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zoneintervention">zoneintervention</label>
                <select multiple name="zoneintervention_id[]" id="zoneintervention" class="form-control" >

                        @foreach($zoneintervention as $zoneintervention)
                         <option value="{{ $zoneintervention->id }}">
                            {{$zoneintervention->code_postal}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Moyenne Avis</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="moyenne_avis" class="form-control"value="{{old('moyenne_avis')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="actif" class="form-control"value="{{old('actif')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**controller**

```
public function create()
{

    $zoneintervention = Zoneintervention::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    $metier = metier::orderBy('libelle_metier', 'desc')->get();
    $tache = tache::orderBy('libelle_tache', 'desc')->get();
    $user = user::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('technicien.create')->with('zoneintervention', $zoneintervention)->with('metier', $metier)->with('tache', $tache)->with('user', $user);

}
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $technicien ->user_id = new user('id');
    $user->nom = $request->input('nom');
    $user->prenom = $request->input('prenom');
    $user->tel = $request->input('tel');
    $user->mobil = $request->input('mobil');
    $user->role = $request->input('role');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->save();
    $technicien = new technicien();
    $technicien->actif = $request->input('actif');
    $technicien->moyenne_avis = $request->input('moyenne_avis');
    $technicien->save();
    $technicien->zoneintervention()->attach($request->zoneintervention_id);
    $technicien->users()->attach($request->user_id);
    $technicien->metier()->attach($request->metier_id);
    $technicien->tache()->attach($request->metier_id);
    return redirect('technicien');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
$technicien->user_id = new user('id');
```

You need first create the user and then get his ID:

```
$user = new user();
$user->nom = $request->input('nom');
$user->prenom = $request->input('prenom');
$user->tel = $request->input('tel');
$user->mobil = $request->input('mobil');
$user->role = $request->input('role');
$user->email = $request->input('email');
$user->password = $request->input('password');
$user->save();

$technicien = new technicien();
$technicien->user_id = $user->id;
$technicien->actif = $request->input('actif');
$technicien->moyenne_avis = $request->input('moyenne_avis');
$technicien->save();
$technicien->zoneintervention()->attach($request->zoneintervention_id);
$technicien->users()->attach($request->user_id);
$technicien->metier()->attach($request->metier_id);
$technicien->tache()->attach($request->metier_id);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried this and i got "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::users()"

Comment: It's not related to the question. You've solved the original question issue and  now it shows you the next error. This error means you did not define `users` relationship in `technicien` model. If you'll not be able to solve this by yourself, please ask a new question and attach all related code and full error message.